# Android: Calling python code from java project

Tags: java, android, python, kivy

I need to call a relatively simple piece of python code (no dependencies) from my java-project for android. I have heard that it is possible to use python via Kivy. Would that be possible?

Comment: Have you done any research? I.e. check the kivy site documentation or anything

Comment: Yes i did. But I have found nothing on that hybrid-approach I need.

Comment: Do you have watch with Jython ? https://wiki.python.org/moin/Jython

Comment: jython requires java SE but android provides just java ME.

Answer (score 1):

[Kivy](http://kivy.org) cannot be easily integrated in an existing Java app, Kivy (the android part) have already a integrated Java application. Python is the main part, and you can execute Java code from Python using [Pyjnius](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Or write direct Java code.

You want the inverse, which is not something we are targeting.

I suggest you to check [android-python27](https://code.google.com/p/android-python27/) project instead.